# Spell Checking a column in Python/Pandas/PyEnchant

Tags: python, pandas, pyenchant

I'm trying to use Pyenchant to spell check each entry in a column called pets in a pandas dataframe called house.

```
import enchant
dict = enchant.Dict("en_US")

for pets in house:
     [pets] = dict.suggest([pets])[0]
```

When I run this code, I get an error about not passing bytestrings to Pyenchant. Not sure what to do. Full error text below:

> File "myfile", line 20, in 
>       [pets] = dict.suggest([pets])[0]
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/enchant/**init**.py", line 662, in suggest
>       word = self._StringClass(word)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/enchant/utils.py", line 152, in **new**
>       raise Error("Don't pass bytestrings to pyenchant")
>   enchant.errors.Error: Don't pass bytestrings to pyenchant

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe contains bytestrings, you will need to decode them before you pass them to `enchant`; you can do this with `.str.decode('utf-8')`. Then to apply your function, the cleanest way to approach this type of situation is usually to use `map` across your Series rather than iterating. (Also you shouldn't shadow the keyword `dict`):

```
checker =  enchant.Dict("en_US")
house = pd.Series([b'caat', b'dogg'])

#decode the bytestrings
house = house.str.decode('utf-8')

#map the spell checker
house.map(lambda x: checker.suggest(x)[0])

# Out[19]:
# 0    cat
# 1    dog
# dtype: object
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting the same error using the decode line of code. I had to load House from a csv using the encoding ISO-8859-1 because it contains weird characters. Not sure the decode is working--> house['pet'] = df2['pet'].str.decode('utf-8'). Thoughts?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not working either. I'm guessing special characters are stuck in the pet column and pyenchant can't interpret them.

Comment: can you find the problematic word and include it in your question?